# Windows runnable jar file (web service client) does not work under Linux. It works under Windows though

Tags: linux, web-services, executable-jar

I export a web service client project into a runable jar file under Windows, then excute it under Linux, the program throws an exception about login.

What may be the problem?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you paste the error, and maybe include the type of library if any you might have used to create the java application?

Comment: Ok, What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/